# Conflict with double google analytics

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, google-analytics

I have a website that only has a full window iframe to a page that already has google analytics, but not on my account(the page isn't mine either). I would like to track my website with Google Analytics and if I put the script in the head site it will say "Tracking not installed". IS there any way to make the browser ignore the google analytics from the iframe?

Comment: Where exactly does the "tracking not installed" message come from?

Comment: in the google analytics cpanel. Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: Oct 26, 2014 6:35:42 AM PDT
The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iframed GA account isn't yours then there is nothing you can do about it. However you can still implement your own analytics by simply doing what you were doing before and putting your own GA code on your pages. You will see that tracking not installed message because it normally takes at least 24 hours for the code to register. In the meantime if there is nothing else wrong with the implementation, you can check in your Real-time reports to see if your own simultaneous visits are recorded. If they are then you are good to go and just need to wait 24 hours for data to show up in your standard reports.

Comment: Thanks for your great repy! :). I guess you are right. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the content of the iframe, it would violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Are you sure you should be using an iframe at all? Either way you can easily add Google Analytics to your own site and track whatever you need with your own Google Analytics ID.

Answer (score 0):

If your analytics code is in the iframe, Google will report that tracking isn't installed as they're checking the parent page, not the iframe. Tracking **will** still work, though. You should see stats come through normally.